# Python Selenium find_elements in multiple pages give the same result all the time

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a simple exmaple of the problem.  I run driver.find_elements(By.ID, "thumbnail")
It works, I click on a random element and I rescrape the info again in a loop and the 2nd time, i always get the exact same results:

```
driver.get("https://www.somepage.com")
time.sleep(7)
items = []

for i in range(3):
    print("LOOP #: " + str(i))
    random_number = random.randint(1, 5)
    items = driver.find_elements(By.ID, "thumbnail")
    url = i.get_attribute("href")
    print(str(url))
    items[random_number].click()
    time.sleep(100)
```

OUTPUT

```
LOOP #: 0
URL 1
URL 2
URL 3
URL 4
LOOP #: 1
URL 1
URL 2
URL 3
URL 4
LOOP #: 2
URL 1
URL 2
URL 3
URL 4
```

The second loop should have different URL. The `find_elements(By.ID, "thumbnail")` still applies

I don't know what I'm doing wrong.
I even tried to add `items.clear()` at the end of the loop, same result.

Comment: Any website link with which it could be tested?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com @AnandGautam

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below answer pertains to `YouTube` since it was given as an example when asked.
When `YouTube` opens, it would have `thumbnail` id, and there are a good collection of those thumbnails. So the strategy is to iterate in rhe range of 3 and in that loop, for each iteration, collect all the elements with the id `thumbnail` and select a random one and fetch it's `href` and then click on it. The question here now is how to reiterate: There are 2 options: (1) Continue with the click and select one of the options (`thumbnail` i suppose) from the left pane, or, (2) click on homepage (`YouTube` icon) and then again continue the iteration process.

I went with the 2nd option, and here it the code for it:

```
driver.get('https://www.youtube.com/')
for i in range(3):
    print("LOOP #: " + str(i))
    time.sleep(10)
    items = driver.find_elements(By.ID, "thumbnail")
    # here, instead of selecting from the items, you are trying to fetch the attribute from i, which is not an element at all and it didn't work for me.
    # I , instead, fetched the href from items stored it in a variable, and clicked on it, then clicked on homepage and reiterated the process
    rand = random.choice(items)
    print(rand.get_attribute('href'))
    rand.click()
    time.sleep(3)
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "(//*[@title='YouTube Home'])[1]").click()
driver.quit()
```

Output:

```
LOOP #: 0
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YIKz49-aGas
LOOP #: 1
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=51Qs0Ej2RUc
LOOP #: 2
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OeShsZPOP-s

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Note: You may replace `time.sleep` with better `explicit wait` like `webdriverwait` if you wish for a robust code. Having said that, YouTube being a Google property, would have a great randomization in the element attributes and gets flaky often. Also, the bot would get detected if there are too many requests.

UPDATED ANSWER:

Updated answer to click on the right pane thumbnails after clicking on the front page thumbnail

```
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get('https://www.youtube.com/')
time.sleep(10)
items = driver.find_elements(By.ID, "thumbnail")
rand = random.choice(items)
print(rand.get_attribute('href'))
rand.click()
time.sleep(3)
for i in range(3):
    print(f"Loop#: {str(i)}")
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "movie_player")))
    yt_left_pane_items = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//*[@id='items']//*[@id='thumbnail']")
    rand_left_pane = random.choice(yt_left_pane_items)
    print(rand_left_pane.get_attribute('href'))
    rand_left_pane.click()
    time.sleep(5)
driver.quit()
```

Imports:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Output:

```
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9YSbflKeOZQ
Loop#: 0
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ENOEgKeI_D0
Loop#: 1
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PeByUAhHXqs
Loop#: 2
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GUHfY84weMw

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: With my code, I was hoping that the first loop gets URL form youtube.com (then I click on 1 URL), and the second loop would fetch new URLS from the suggested URL (right side of the video that was click on loop 1.

Not to re-fetch from youtube.com on loop 2 and 3.... but to fetch form the right side (suggested videos), which also have ID = thumbnail.

Comment: @user3011784, understood your query now and updated the answer above per your comment. What is happening is thumbnails of right pane are different from the main page(as I observed) as you can see in the code. Hence I had changed the structure. First it will randomly select a video from the home page, and then it will loop through range of 3 for right page suggested videos.